# Changing a class with a variable as the id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, class, variables

Hey all, I am not quite getting why this doesn't seem to be working.
The alert pops out the correct id, but the removeClass does not seem to be firing.
What am I doing wrong?

```
function testClassSwitch(t_id) {
    alert("Do things to a button with this ID: " + t_id);
    $(t_id).removeClass("add-button");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: to toggle classes use toggleClass...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your `t_id` have the `#` [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) on it?

Comment: Oh, son of a! *facepalm* Thanks so much, something so simple. ;-/

Comment: No worries TwstdElf. This one is easy to miss :P.

Comment: @TwstdElf - agreed, easy mistake to make :)

Answer (score 3):

add `#` before the id like this

```
function testClassSwitch(t_id) {
    alert("Do things to a button with this ID: " + t_id);
    $('#' + t_id).removeClass("add-button");
}
```